# Removing everything after a character in a column in R

Tags: r, character

I need to remove everything after the question mark in a column.

I have a data set EX:

```
my.data

BABY      MOM      LANDING
mark      dina     www.example.com/?kdvhzkajvkadjf
tom       becky    www.example.com/?ghkadkho[qeu
brad      tina     www.example.com/?klsdfngal;j
```

I want my new data to be:

```
new.data

BABY      MOM      LANDING
mark      dina     www.example.com/?
tom       becky    www.example.com/?
brad      tina     www.example.com/?
```

How do I tell R to remove everything after the `?` in `my.data$LANDING` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the characters that are after `?`.  We use a positive lookbehind  (`(?<=\\?).*`) to match one or more character (`.`) that is preceded by `?` and replace it with `''`.

```
 my.data$LANDING <- sub('(?<=\\?).*$', '', my.data$LANDING, perl=TRUE)
 my.data
 #  BABY   MOM       LANDING
 #1 mark  dina www.example.com/?
 #2  tom becky www.example.com/?
 #3 brad  tina www.example.com/?
```

Or another option would be to use `capture groups` and then replace the second argument with the capture group (`\\1`).

```
 my.data$LANDING <- sub('([^?]+\\?).*', '\\1', my.data$LANDING)
```

Here, we match all characters that are not `?` (`[^?]+`) followed by `?` (`\\?`) and use parentheses to capture as a group (`([^?]+\\?)`), and we leave the rest of characters not in the group (`.*`).

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments, we can match the `?` and the rest of the characters (`.*`), and replace it by `\\?` as the second argument.

```
  my.data$LANDING <- sub("\\?.*","\\?",my.data$LANDING)
```

Comment: Instead of a lookbehind, you could replace the query with a blank string: `sub("\\?.*","\\?",my.data$LANDING)`

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed.